Add custom validation before form submission in ClickFunnels
On ClickFunnels, I am trying to add some custom validation for an input field (email) as the built-in ones are not enough for my use case.
The validation use an external api call to validate the email and is not performed using a regex, so I can't just use pattern=...
I first tried to add the validation on the email blur/change event using setCustomValidity but it doesn't seem to prevent the submit event from being fired and the from being submitted.
var emailField=$('input[name="email"]');
$(emailField).on('blur', async function() {
    const isValid = await isEmailValid();
    if (isValid) {
        emailField[0].setCustomValidity("");
    } else {
        emailField[0].setCustomValidity("Invalid field.");
    }
    emailField[0].reportValidity();
});

So, I tried to modify the submit event adding a script on the Footer Code part.
$(document).on('submit', 'form', async function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var emailValid = await isEmailValid();
    if (!emailValid) {
        return false;
    } else {
        event.target.submit();
    }
});

However, it seems that if the form is not submitted (doesn't reach the  event.target.submit(); line), it can't be called again by clicking on the submit button or pressing ENTER (that works otherwise).
Any idea as to why it prevents me from calling the submit event several times ?
